# Recommendation for an indexing and search engine on semi-structured data

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, search, indexing, solr

I have a semi-structured time-series data in JSON format. I say semi-structured because some fields may or may not be present or maybe nested based on the availability of some data.

Say the data format is,

```
title: "Dummy",
date: "13-10-2019",
a: string-value,
.
.
.
x: int-value,
y: string-value,
z: int-value,
```

I have millions of such records and each record's size varies from 10Kb to 10Mb. I cannot store them in a nosql or a sql database since some of the string values are unstructured logs of about 10-20 lines and some other fields are some fixed integers within a given range.

I need to be able to search and retrieve any field as fast as possible.
Say If I give the value of x and I should be able to get all the dates with that x value or values of all the y's with that corresponding x's value.

Note: I don't want to get entire JSON record, I just want to get the value of one field given the value of another field. But the data is huge so indexing each and every field may not be possible. And also the software needs to have a good Java API.

So I need a software recommendation for a search and retrieval engine. I am currently considering solr and ELK stack(elasticsearch). I am open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Both ES and Solr should work fine. It'll require planning and tuning, but it's a far to open question to give an answer that could consider all possible issues with your specific case. Make a prototype and go from there.

Comment: 10Mb record is pretty huge. You have to target witch fields need to be indexed and how you have to querry them, otherwise, you would have to build a big cluster (witch could have to grow up very fast if you dont have TTL).

Comment: @LeBigCat As you said not all fields will be indexed. Only quantifiable fields will be indexed, which will reduce the load a lot. But still my doubt is will I be able to get the records by querying like I do in normal SQL databases. (both on indexed and not indexed fields)

Comment: @MatsLindh I have heard that Solr is better for text based searching. And also should I consider Mongo as well for the task?

Comment: @MatsLindh And which one has better Java APIs?

Comment: ES has better API, and is built for logging. ES may have license fees though in some cases. Solr is good too.

Comment: Solr and ES both uses Lucene as their backend, so their search capabilities are mostly the same. ES handles arbitrary nested JSON better. The API used from Java is similar in both cases.

Comment: @MatsLindh Can I ingest data into ES? Like I would in Mongo DB. Because I not only need to index and search the documents, I also have to store them in a proper DB (sql or nosql). And also while inserting I want to find out the delta between two fields and store them as well. Mongo won't do because it only allows for a maximum record size of 16Mb which will become a bottleneck in the future. So is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Depends on what you need the data for. Usually you'd not have your search solution as your primary storage, since changing indexing requirements (i.e. changing the analysis chain) will require reindexing your content - which means you'll have to resubmit it to your search node / cluster again for reprocessing. You can use `mongo-connector` to get data replicated in realtime to Solr or ES, and possibly apply the necessary processing as well.